# IOS Parse's Anypic Installation

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have downloaded Parse's app, Anypic, but cannot get it to run properly on my phone. I have completed all of the required steps and it says "build succeeded" when I run it.

However, all that shows up is a black screen and a Facebook "login" button. When the button is clicked, you can login to Facebook but then it just changes the button to say "log out" which is not exactly wha

I have attached a picture with all my warnings I get. Are the warnings the issue or is there something else I need to change in the code? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should change handleFacebookSession part to look like this:

```
- (void)handleFacebookSession {
if ([PFUser currentUser]) {
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(logInViewControllerDidLogUserIn:)]) {
        [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(logInViewControllerDidLogUserIn:) withObject:[PFUser currentUser]];
    }
    return;
}

NSArray *permissionsArray = @[ @"public_profile",
                               @"user_friends",
                               @"email"];

self.hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];

// Login PFUser using Facebook
[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {

    if (!user) {
        NSString *errorMessage = nil;
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
            errorMessage = @"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.";
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Uh oh. An error occurred: %@", error);
            errorMessage = [error localizedDescription];
        }
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Log In Error"
                                                        message:errorMessage
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"Dismiss", nil];
        [alert show];
    } else {
        if (user.isNew) {
            NSLog(@"User with facebook signed up and logged in!");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"User with facebook logged in!");
        }

        if (!error) {
            [self.hud removeFromSuperview];
            if (self.delegate) {
                if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(logInViewControllerDidLogUserIn:)]) {
                    [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(logInViewControllerDidLogUserIn:) withObject:user];
                }
            }
        } else {
            [self cancelLogIn:error];
        }
    }
}];}
```

Found [here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Anypic/issues/43).